# Expectation of KL-divergence only as the log ratio of the probabilities

Tags: expected-value, kullback-leibler

In the [DPO paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2305.18290), and in particular in the proof attached below, how can we expand the KL divergence only as the log ratio of the probabilities of the two distributions?

[image: Appendix A.1 of the DPO paper]

According to the definition the log should also be multiplied by the $\pi(y|x)$ term.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The term $\pi (y \mid x)$ is the density of the random variable $y$ in the second line of the display. Thus, it is part of taking the expectation $\mathbb{E}_{y \sim \pi (y \mid x)}$ and cannot appear 'again'. More precisely, we have
$$
\mathbb{D}_{KL} \left( p \Vert q \right) = \int  p(y) \log \left( \frac{p(y) }{ q(y)} \right) \, \mathrm{d} y  =  \mathrm{E}_{y \sim p} \left[ \log \left( \frac{p(y)}{q(y)} \right) \right]
$$
for probability densities $p$ and $q$ by the definition of $\mathbb{E}$.

Comment: I can understand the intuition, but could you please expand the proof step by step? Thanks!

Comment: @goodolddays Added the identity in question

Comment: I think there still something missing in the derivation you've posted: we have to prove that E[E[X]] = E[X], if the expectation is over the same probability distribution. Because the KL-Divergence is inside an expectation, so it becomes an expectation of an expectation.

Comment: @goodolddays That identity holds trivially. At the same time, I don't see how the KL-divergence is inside an expectation.